# Add Cookies to separate headers in nginX proxy server

Tags: cookies, nginx, header, reverse-proxy

**The problem** is that I want to get cookie and send each cookie in header in `nginX`. I already know that setting header in nginX is by using `proxy_set_header`, but the **my question** is how to get different cookies and set their values in headers?

```
proxy_set_header x-user $user;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We just needed to get `Cookie` content. To get this job done we should have been used the `$cookie_COOKIE_NAME`:

```
proxy_set_header x-client-id $cookie_header_x_client_id;
proxy_set_header x-app-version $cookie_header_x_app_version;
proxy_set_header Authorization $cookie_header_authorization;
```